# AWS S3 bucket images - React Native app keeps showing old image

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, caching

My app keeps showing my old image. I don't have bucket versioning. I tried restarting the app but it keeps showing this old image.. Is it caching somehow? Any tips on how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image component of React-Native provides a cache extension for iOS for the source prop. Can you please try to set the cache to "reload"?

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png',
    cache: 'reload'
    headers: {Pragma: 'no-cache'} // Android Support
  }}
  style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
/>
```

Attention the support is only for iOS

Comment: what about android?

Comment: @Abhi It is also possible to set general HTTP headers and thus set no-cache in the header.  As follows in addition to the uri key:
headers: {
      Pragma: 'no-cache
    },

Comment: okay, thanks I will check I was facing the same issue after updating the image. the old image was showing

Comment: its not working for me I updating an image (using s3 bucket) image is not updating after clearing the cache of app new image is loading

Comment: @Abhi okay one thing you can try is to write an custom image component and whenever you pass an url you transform the url to url += '?random_number=' new Date().getTime(). So it will always load the latest image. It's a quick hack.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue when fetching image from AWS S3. The uri remains the same but the actual content/image was changing. This is how I solved it:

1. I created my custom image component which accept `dynamic` property. This is because I wanted to update that component for specific image uri not for all.
2. I then use axios to get response header of the file. This is because aws s3 in response header gives the last updated time of the image.
3. In the end, I concatenate a string at the end of the uri and update the state, so that component rerender.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Image as NativeImage, ImageProps } from 'react-native'
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native-paper'
import axios from 'axios';

const Image = (props: ImageProps) => {
    const [path, setPath] = useState("")
    const checkFileMetadata = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.head(props.source.uri)
            setPath(props.source.uri + "?t=" + Date.now(response.headers?.["last-modified"]))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.hasOwnProperty("dynamic")) {
            checkFileMetadata()
        }
    }, [])
    if (props.hasOwnProperty("dynamic")) {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.root, props.style]}>
                {
                    path && (
                        <NativeImage
                            {...props}
                            source={{ ...props.source, uri: path }}
                            style={[styles.imageView, props.style]}
                        />
                    )
                }
                <View style={styles.loaderRoot}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={18} color='rgba(0,0,0,1)' />
                </View>
            </View >
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={[styles.root, props.style]}>
            <NativeImage
                {...props}
                style={[styles.imageView, props.style]}
            />
            <View style={styles.loaderRoot}>
                <ActivityIndicator size={18} color='rgba(0,0,0,1)' />
            </View>
        </View >
    )
}

export default Image

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        overflow: "hidden"
    },
    imageView: {
        zIndex: 2
    },
    loaderRoot: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        zIndex: 1
    }
})
```

Benefit of using this method is we can make use of React Native Image caching mechanism.